# Sole Proprietor LLC quarterly estimated tax payment

Tags: united-states, income-tax, limited-liability-company, sole-proprietorship

This is going to be my first quarterly estimated federal tax payment for a single member llc (treated as disregarded entity- sole proprietor). I see online that for annual taxes, I need to fill out schedule C, but I do not see any schedule C form when making the quarterly tax payments.

1. Does schedule C exist for quarterly payments?
2. Am I supposed to simply make the payment using Form 1040-ES without worrying about that the income gets reported as business income?

Also, another question:

I file joint returns with my spouse but I am the single owner of the LLC. But when we make our tax payment he is the primary person (I mean he gets listed as the Primary SSN number) and I get listed as the spouse (secondary SSN number). 
Now if I am filling out Form 1040ES to pay my estimated quarterly payments for the sole-proprietorship, do I still list him as the primary person?

Also, my LLC has its own EIN but form 1040ES has no place to insert the LLCs EIN number. So I am kinda confused how to go about making these payments?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does schedule C exist for quarterly payments?

No.

> Am I supposed to simply make the payment using Form 1040-ES without worrying about that the income gets reported as business income?

You're just supposed to pay 1/4 of what you estimate your taxes will be. If your LLC is a disregarded entity, then it does not have to file or pay any taxes of its own. As far as the IRS is concerned, your LLC is just you and does not have to pay any taxes itself.

The penalty for underpaying your quarterly estimated taxes is minimal so long as the full due amount is paid by the year's filing deadline and the IRS will automatically compute the penalty and bill you for it. I wouldn't worry too much about getting it exactly right your first year because that tends to be almost impossible anyway.